# integration bus httprequest content length

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

For sending a PUT request to a http server, I'm using an HttpRequest node. The message passes through an ESQL compute node. The issue is that the content length of the message sent to server is 0. The request does not contains any data, although the variable used for the body of the message has content. 
How can I pass the content of a put http request from esql code?

The esql code is as follows:

```
SET OutputLocalEnvironment = InputLocalEnvironment; 
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestURL = ...; 
SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."Content-Type" = 'text/plain'; 
SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."Authorization" = 'Bearer ' || … ; 
SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."Host" = ...'; 
SET OutputRoot.BLOB = CAST(InputRoot.BLOB.BLOB as char CCSID 1208 Encoding 815);
```

The configuration of the HTTPRequest node is

HttpSettings

```
HTTP method: PUT 
HTTP version 1.1 
Enable keep-alive <checked> 

Request Timeout: 20 
HTTP Proxy Location : <blank> 
Follow HTTP redirection: <unchecked> 

Advanced: 
Use whole input message as request : <un-checked> 
Request Message Location in Tree : InputRoot.BLOB 
Replace input message with web-service response: <checked> 
Generate default HTTP headers : <un-checked> 

VALIDATION: None
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try :

```
SET OutputRoot.BLOB.BLOB = CAST(InputRoot.BLOB.BLOB as char CCSID 1208 Encoding 815);
```

(I don't have the logical explanation, but you did it correctly for the input)
By the way, this line looks a bit strange to me

Comment: This is correct - The first 'BLOB' is the name of the parser, the second 'BLOB' is the name of the field within that parser. The BLOB parser only allows a singe field called 'BLOB' because a BLOB cannot, by definition, have any internal structure.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation about the BLOB parser :)

Comment: Yep BLOB BLOB it's a bit confusing until it becomes a habit. As Kimbert points out that first level element is the parser name.

Answer (score 0):

into your compute node just write this and your input messages go to output

```
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE Compute
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        CALL CopyMessageHeaders();
        CALL CopyEntireMessage();


        RETURN TRUE;
    END;

    CREATE PROCEDURE CopyMessageHeaders() BEGIN
        DECLARE I INTEGER 1;
        DECLARE J INTEGER;
        SET J = CARDINALITY(InputRoot.*[]);
        WHILE I < J DO
            SET OutputRoot.*[I] = InputRoot.*[I];
            SET I = I + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END;

    CREATE PROCEDURE CopyEntireMessage() BEGIN
        SET OutputRoot = InputRoot;
    END;
END MODULE;
```

hope this works for you